# How do I toggle a class in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a button that I want to be able to toggle a class on a div to hide and show the div how would I do that in Angular?

HTML

```
<div id="chatsidebar">
    <app-chatsidebar></app-chatsidebar>
</div>
<div>
    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info" (click)="togglesideBar()">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></i>
        Toggle Sidebar
    </button>
</div>
```

I want to add the class "active" onto the #chatsidebar div

app.component.ts

```
togglesideBar() {

}
```

Thanks

Comment: use a boolean variable inside togglesideBar() method, if variable is true trun it to false and vise varsa.

Comment: *I cant find a solution anywhere* That's odd. The solution is given in hundreds or thousands of intros, tutorials, blog posts, Q&A right here on SO, and documentation pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering this part of your question:

> I want to add the class "active" onto the #chatsidebar div

To do it, you can use [NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass). NgClass allows you to add or remove any class to or from an element based on the given condition. Your code will looks something like this:

*HTML*

```
<div id="chatsidebar" [ngClass]="{'active': isSideBarActive}"> <!-- this ngClass will add or remove `active` class based on the `isSideBarActive` value -->
    <app-chatsidebar></app-chatsidebar>
</div>
<div>
    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info" (click)="togglesideBar()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></i>
        Toggle Sidebar
    </button>
</div>
```

*Component*

```
isSideBarActive: boolean = true; // initial value can be set to either `false` or `true`, depends on our need

togglesideBar() {
    this.isSideBarActive = !this.isSideBarActive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a variable in your component something like

```
isShowChatSidebar:boolean=true;
```

then modify your method and html

```
togglesideBar() {
this.isShowChatSidebar=!this.isShowChatSidebar
}

<div id="chatsidebar" [ngClass]="{'active': isShowChatSidebar}">>
    <app-chatsidebar></app-chatsidebar>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey I did this but I want to toggle the class .active on and off the chatsidebar do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="chatsidebar" *ngIf="status">
        <app-chatsidebar></app-chatsidebar>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info" (click)="togglesideBar()">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></i>
            Toggle Sidebar
        </button>
    </div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
status:boolean=true;
togglesideBar() {
      if(this.status == true) this.status=false;
      else this.status = true;
}
```

Demo: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/fNoXWhUhMaUoeMihbGYd?p=preview

Comment: Is this somehow different/better than `this.status = !this.status;`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try below.

```
<div id="chatsidebar" class="{{activeClass}}"> ... </div>
```

and on your component define a property and set the class value on toggle function

```
    // On Component
    activeClass : string = "";
    ...

    togglesideBar() {
        this.activeClass = 'active'
    }
```

it shall work, but may not the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a class named `hide`:

```
<div [class.hide]="hide">
    <app-chatsidebar></app-chatsidebar>
</div>

<div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="togglesideBar()">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-right"></i>
        Toggle Sidebar
    </button>
</div>

togglesideBar() { this.hide = !this.hide; }
```

This will hide the element in question, while leaving it in the DOM. The other solutions using `*ngIf` will add and remove the element to and from the DOM. There are subtle reasons in specific cases to prefer one over the other, well described in the on-line documentation you have already read. In this case, it doesn't really matter.

The `[class.className]=boolean` format is just one of several ways to control classes in Angular. For instance, you could also have said:

```
[ngClass]="{'hide': hide}"
```

This is slightly more flexible because you can add/remove multiple classes at once.

Since you are using glyphicons, you are probably using Bootstrap, so you most likely already have the `hide` class defined.

As an aside, you rarely need IDs, and using them is pretty much of an anti-pattern in Angular.